# How do I export all pages below a page in confluence using a script

Tags: scripting, confluence

I'm capturing meeting notes in a page structure in confluence. I want to export all the meeting notes to a share drive for others to read. I've found notes on how to export a page or a space but not the pages below a page.  e.g. I want everything below "Parent Page" but not anything else.

e.g.

```
  Space
    Unrelated Pages
    Unrelated Pages
    Parent of Parent
      Parent Page
          Child Page 1
          Child Page 2
          Child page 3
```

I want to drag the child pages to a share drive. I'm looking to use one of the following e.g. curl, .bat files, python, R etc.

This is on the cloud version of confluence

Comment: Why not just give "the others" read permission to confluence? :S

Answer (score 6):

Go to the *Space directory*, find the relevant space and click the (i) icon there to get to the space details page. From there, click either *Space Operations/PDF Export*, or *Content Tools/Export*, then choose *Custom Export*. You’ll be able to select the list of pages to be exported. (All pages under a given page can be selected by clicking *Deselect All* and then clicking the checkbox for the parent page. All child pages will be selected automatically.)

Or, if you are a space administrator:

1. Go to the *Space settings*
2. From there, click *Manage space/Export space*
   [image]
3. Choose PDF format or other
4. Then choose *Custom Export*.

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct was to give the "other" folks who want to read the meeting notes, (read) access to confluence itself - thats what confluence was meant for.

But if you're dead set on living in the 90s and downloading stuff to another drive, you can try the [Page Tree Word Exporter plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.confluence.plugin.pagetreeexporter.pagetree-word-exporter-plugin/cloud/overview) (But this is manual)

Script wise, you can do the following:

1. Get all the child pages with the REST API: Make a GET call to

   https://confluence-domain.com/rest/api/content/search?cql=parent={Parent Page-id}

This will return a "results" array with info about the child pages. Parse out the "id" fields. (Hint: if you are using bash, you can use the beautiful jq library https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

2. Once you have the child page IDs, you can export each individually to PDF using:

   ```
   wget https://confluence-domain.com/spaces/flyingpdf/pdfpageexport.action?pageId=xxxx -O mypage.pdf
   ```

This blog might help you in your coding: http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 (bottom left):

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

To export all pages below a page, check the parent page.

If the export is absent, the admin needs to give you the permissions for it.